# How to check for inactive users in Django in ModelBackEnd

Tags: django, django-models

How would I check for inactive custom users in ModelBackEnd without returning None (like what AllowAllUsersModelBackend does)? Here's what I have so far:

```
from django.contrib.auth import backends, get_user_model
from django.db.models import Q
UserModel = get_user_model()


class ModelBackend(backends.ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        if username is None:
            username = kwargs.get(UserModel.USERNAME_FIELD)
        try:
            # user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
            # You can customise what the given username is checked against, here I compare to both username and email fields of the User model
            user = UserModel.objects.get(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
            #print("what is going on")
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            # Run the default password hasher once to reduce the timing
            # difference between an existing and a nonexistent user (#20760).
            UserModel().set_password(password)
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                return user
        return super().authenticate(request, username, password, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Allow inactive users to login?

Comment: I just need to detect accounts with is_active = False during login.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: I just wanted to prevent disabled accounts from logging back in.  I figured it out by just returning users in the try statement.

Comment: @IainShelvington do you know how to make a page for staff owners, how to accept and deny inactive users. Delete or make them is_active=True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the condition to the query when you are getting the user instance

```
user = UserModel.objects.exclude(is_active=False).get(Q(username__iexact=username) | Q(email__iexact=username))
```